# XSLT to add key to child nodes from parent element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm importing XML to an Access database.  During the conversion, all relationships between data are lost.  Using XSLT, I'm perpetuating the ID down through child nodes.  using this, where `Id` is the parent element being added to child nodes:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[Id]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[Id]/Id | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem I'm running into using this approach is there are other elements outside of the parent node that also have the `Id` element or variations of it, e.g. `AccountId` or something similar. When I attempt to use this in addition to the code above, some instances of `Id` go missing in previous nodes.

```
   <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[AccountId]/AccountId | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I apologize as I don't know the appropriate language to use here as I don't know XSLT/XML very well...but what I I'm trying to accomplish is to narrow the focus of the template application to the node just below the document node (the base element node?) so that I can apply the template at a more granular level.  Or find some way of perpetuating IDs when there are multiple instances of it that aren't necessarily related (e.g. example below with `Link`, `Alice` and `Balance` node). Notice in the first output, the `Id` is being perpetuated down to child nodes.

Here's an example.

XML:

```
<Response>


<Alices>
    <Alice>
        <Id>12345</Id>
        <Bobbers>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Bobs>
                <Bob>
                    <Organization>
                        <Name>John Doe</Name>
                        <ABB>987654</ABB>
                        <ContactDetails>
                            <Adds>
                                <Add>
                                    <Type>Postal</Type>
                                    <Line1>PO BOX 12345</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                                <Add>
                                    <Type>Street</Type>
                                    <Line1>123 Anywhere</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                            </Adds>
                            <PNs>
                                <PN>
                                    <Type>Mobile</Type>
                                    <Number>11111111</Number>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </PN>
                            </PNs>
                            <EMs>
                                <EM>
                                    <Type>Personal</Type>
                                    <Add>j.doe@anywhere.com</Add>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </EM>
                            </EMs>
                            <PreferredContactMethod>Email</PreferredContactMethod>
                        </ContactDetails>
                        <Contacts>
                            <Contact>
                                <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                                <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                            </Contact>
                        </Contacts>
                    </Organization>
                </Bob>
            </Bobs>
        </Bobbers>
        <Jons>
            <Jon>
                <Id>012991</Id>
                <PrimaryJon>true</PrimaryJon>
                <StartDate>1900-01-01</StartDate>
            </Jon>
        </Jons>
    </Alice>
        <Movements>
            <Movement>
                <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
                <InvestmentCode>ABI</InvestmentCode>
                <Exchange>BRU</Exchange>
                <Id>YabbaDabba</Id>
                <Links>
                    <Link>
                        <Id>YabbaDabbaDoo</Id>
                        <Type>Stone</Type>
                    </Link>
                </Links>
            </Movement>
        </Movements>
        <Balances>
            <Balance>
                <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
                <Value>123456</Value>
                <Investments>
                    <Investment>
                        <Code>JJJ</Code>
                        <UnitBalance>
                            <Total>112.000000</Total>
                        </UnitBalance>
                    </Investment>
                </Investments>
            </Balance>
        </Balances>
</Alices>

</Response>
```

Using this XSLT, without the AcctId template. Note I'm changing an element name in the `Link` node from `Id` to `LinkId` and it's parent element `Id` to `TransactionId` to distinguish the two.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 
    <xsl:template match="Response/Alices/Movements/Movement/Id">
        <TransactionID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </TransactionID>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@TransactionID">
        <xsl:attribute name="TransactionID">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
      <xsl:template match="Response/Alices/Movements/Movement/Links/Link/Id">
        <LinkedTransactionID>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </LinkedTransactionID>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@LinkedTransactionID">
        <xsl:attribute name="LinkedTransactionID">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[Id]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[Id]/Id | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
 
 
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields this. `Id` elements are perpetuated from the `Alice` node down to its children.  Also in `link` node, the `TransactionId` is also being pushed down from its parent.  XSLT changes the name of this `TransactionId` from `Id` to `TransactionId`.

```
<Response>
   <Alices>
      <Alice>
         <Id>12345</Id>
         <Bobbers>
            <Id>12345</Id>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Bobs>
               <Bob>
                  <Organization>
                     <Id>12345</Id>
                     <Name>John Doe</Name>
                     <ABB>987654</ABB>
                     <ContactDetails>
                        <Id>12345</Id>
                        <Adds>
                           <Add>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Postal</Type>
                              <Line1>PO BOX 12345</Line1>
                              <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                              <State>ENE</State>
                              <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                              <Country>GB</Country>
                              <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                           </Add>
                           <Add>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Street</Type>
                              <Line1>123 Anywhere</Line1>
                              <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                              <State>ENE</State>
                              <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                              <Country>GB</Country>
                              <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                           </Add>
                        </Adds>
                        <PNs>
                           <PN>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Mobile</Type>
                              <Number>11111111</Number>
                              <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                           </PN>
                        </PNs>
                        <EMs>
                           <EM>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Personal</Type>
                              <Add>j.doe@anywhere.com</Add>
                              <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                           </EM>
                        </EMs>
                        <PreferredContactMethod>Email</PreferredContactMethod>
                     </ContactDetails>
                     <Contacts>
                        <Contact>
                           <Id>12345</Id>
                           <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                           <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                        </Contact>
                     </Contacts>
                  </Organization>
               </Bob>
            </Bobs>
         </Bobbers>
         <Jons>
            <Jon>
               <Id>12345</Id>
               <Id>012991</Id>
               <PrimaryJon>true</PrimaryJon>
               <StartDate>1900-01-01</StartDate>
            </Jon>
         </Jons>
      </Alice>
      <Movements>
         <Movement>
            <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
            <InvestmentCode>ABI</InvestmentCode>
            <Exchange>BRU</Exchange>
            <TransactionID>YabbaDabba</TransactionID>
            <Links>
               <Link>
                  <TransactionID>YabbaDabba</TransactionID>
                  <LinkedTransactionID>YabbaDabbaDoo</LinkedTransactionID>
                  <Type>Stone</Type>
               </Link>
            </Links>
         </Movement>
      </Movements>
      <Balances>
         <Balance>
            <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
            <Value>123456</Value>
            <Investments>
               <Investment>
                  <Code>JJJ</Code>
                  <UnitBalance>
                     <Total>112.000000</Total>
                  </UnitBalance>
               </Investment>
            </Investments>
         </Balance>
      </Balances>
   </Alices>
</Response>
```

Emphasis on this section, which in particular is what I wanted to see:

```
<Link>
   <TransactionID>YabbaDabba</TransactionID>
   <LinkedTransactionID>YabbaDabbaDoo</LinkedTransactionID>
   <Type>Stone</Type>
</Link>
```

However if I *add* this to the XSLT in order to perpetuate the `AccountId` in the `Balance` node to the `Investment` node, the `Link` node ID is changed. Relevant section is below the full output.

```
    <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[AccountId]/AccountId | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Yields this, where the `link` node loses its parent's ID:

```
<Response>
   <Alices>
      <Alice>
         <Id>12345</Id>
         <Bobbers>
            <Id>12345</Id>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Bobs>
               <Bob>
                  <Organization>
                     <Id>12345</Id>
                     <Name>John Doe</Name>
                     <ABB>987654</ABB>
                     <ContactDetails>
                        <Id>12345</Id>
                        <Adds>
                           <Add>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Postal</Type>
                              <Line1>PO BOX 12345</Line1>
                              <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                              <State>ENE</State>
                              <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                              <Country>GB</Country>
                              <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                           </Add>
                           <Add>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Street</Type>
                              <Line1>123 Anywhere</Line1>
                              <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                              <State>ENE</State>
                              <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                              <Country>GB</Country>
                              <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                           </Add>
                        </Adds>
                        <PNs>
                           <PN>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Mobile</Type>
                              <Number>11111111</Number>
                              <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                           </PN>
                        </PNs>
                        <EMs>
                           <EM>
                              <Id>12345</Id>
                              <Type>Personal</Type>
                              <Add>j.doe@anywhere.com</Add>
                              <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                           </EM>
                        </EMs>
                        <PreferredContactMethod>Email</PreferredContactMethod>
                     </ContactDetails>
                     <Contacts>
                        <Contact>
                           <Id>12345</Id>
                           <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                           <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                        </Contact>
                     </Contacts>
                  </Organization>
               </Bob>
            </Bobs>
         </Bobbers>
         <Jons>
            <Jon>
               <Id>12345</Id>
               <Id>012991</Id>
               <PrimaryJon>true</PrimaryJon>
               <StartDate>1900-01-01</StartDate>
            </Jon>
         </Jons>
      </Alice>
      <Movements>
         <Movement>
            <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
            <InvestmentCode>ABI</InvestmentCode>
            <Exchange>BRU</Exchange>
            <TransactionID>YabbaDabba</TransactionID>
            <Links>
               <Link>
                  <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
                  <LinkedTransactionID>YabbaDabbaDoo</LinkedTransactionID>
                  <Type>Stone</Type>
               </Link>
            </Links>
         </Movement>
      </Movements>
      <Balances>
         <Balance>
            <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
            <Value>123456</Value>
            <Investments>
               <Investment>
                  <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
                  <Code>JJJ</Code>
                  <UnitBalance>
                     <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
                     <Total>112.000000</Total>
                  </UnitBalance>
               </Investment>
            </Investments>
         </Balance>
      </Balances>
   </Alices>
</Response>
```

Emphasis on these nodes:

```
<Link>
  <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
  <LinkedTransactionID>YabbaDabbaDoo</LinkedTransactionID>
  <Type>Stone</Type>
</Link>
```

and this section is now showing the parent's ID, as I wanted.

```
<Investment>
    <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
    <Code>JJJ</Code>
    <UnitBalance>
      <AccountId>J54321</AccountId>
      <Total>112.000000</Total>
    </UnitBalance>
</Investment>
```

I believe in this situation the issue is that `Movement` node also has `AccountId` and some child nodes have `Id` elements, both affected by the XSLT.  So if I need to perpetuate IDs to child nodes from the parent nodes when there are multiple IDs that don't necessarily relate, how do I write the XSLT so that there is no conflict between the templates I'm trying to apply to the same node?

Comment: Each node is handled once and only by one matching template, your introduction giving both `<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[Id]]">` and `<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">` and then complaining that "some instances of Id go missing in previous nodes" seems to suggest you expect both templates to be applied somehow. I got lost in the way too lengthy code samples to tell whether you can have elements with both `Id` and `AccountId` and to understand where you want those to be copied to.

Comment: So the input has e.g. `<Link><Id>YabbaDabbaDoo</Id><Type>Stone</Type></Link>` and you want to perform two transformations, transform the `Id` child to `<LinkedTransactionID>YabbaDabbaDoo</LinkedTransactionID>` and copy in the ancestor's `Id` to `TransactionID`. But what is that you want to do with the ancestor's `<AccountId>J54321</AccountId>`? Your second templates processes it and copies it. It seems you don't want that to happen for that `Link` element. What are the criteria to copy in the ancestor's `AccountId`? When, for which elements do you want that to happen, for which ones not?

Comment: @MartinHonnen It would be fine to perpetuate ```<AccountId>J54321</AccountId>``` to ```link```, but that information is ascertainable in the tables as they're brought into the Access database, whereas ```LinkedTransactionId``` and ```TransactionId``` is not.  My trouble is with the double set of templates, the ```TransactionId``` is being replaced by the ```AccountId``` which doesn't leave me with a way of connecting ```TransactionId``` and ```LinkedTransactionId```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps restrict the application of the second template with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and not(Id) and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">
```

to only be used if the element doesn't have an `Id` child, like those `Link` elements have.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. If you don't mind, could you explain what ```*[*[not(*)]``` means?  Given the additional context of what you've put together, I gather the remainder is saying copy the element where any ancestor element is called ```AccountId``` but where ```Id``` doesn't exist in the current node?

Comment: The pattern part `match="*[*[not(*)]` basically matches any element having at least one child that has no child elements itself as it seemed from your samples you wanted the `Id` copied in inside of container elements that have plain data children but not for container that themselves only contain container elements.

Comment: understood, thank you.

Comment: So this does resolve the issue I was seeing with the ```link``` container and the ```Investment``` container.  However I am now noticing that the ```Id``` that was pushed down to child containers in ```Alice``` to its child containers have lost their inherited Id. Was this suggestion to be used like this (in XSLT)?

Comment: to the above comment: ```<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and not(Id) and ancestor::*[AccountId]]"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[Id]/Id | *"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>``` with ```<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[AccountId]]"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[AccountId]/AccountId | *"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>```

Comment: The suggestion was to use `<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and not(Id) and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">` instead of the `<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[AccountId]]">`. The template with `<xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[Id]]">` needs no change.

Comment: perfect, thanks.